# ng-animate pulse background color by adding class, then removing class

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm working on a simple animation that pulses the background color when an array changes.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/27K6B6vHa4ayuPbgRSP3?p=preview

My directive:

```
app.directive('animateOnChange', ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    scope.$watchCollection(attr.animateOnChange, function() {
      $animate.addClass(elem, 'on').then(function() {
        $animate.removeClass(elem, 'on');
      });
    });
  };
}]);
```

It seems that `addClass` and `removeClass` run at the same time, and the `on` class is never removed. It fades in fine, but doesn't fade out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap it in a $timeout callback to force two different digests:

```
app.directive('animateOnChange', ['$animate', '$timeout', function($animate, $timeout) {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    scope.$watchCollection(attr.animateOnChange, function() {
      console.log('items changed');
      $animate.addClass(elem, 'on').then(function() {
        $timeout(function(){
          $animate.removeClass(elem, 'on');
        }, 0);
      });
    });
  };
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/cWciPY4zJ8lSr31CECMS?p=preview

There are more ways to do it, but this one is probably the easiest.

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly.